# Font Awesome 'fa-life-ring' doesn't show

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

### Problem

**fa-life-ring** refuses to show in the below code. I have tried removing the `fa-5x`, removing the `text-align: center;` but nothing helps. I have also tried another icon and this works ok then.

### Code

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="text-align: center;">
      <i class="fa fa-file-text fa-5x"></i>
      <h3>Quotes</h6>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse semper ipsum ut commodo tristique.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Quotes</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4" style="text-align: center;">
      <i class="fa fa-life-ring fa-5x"></i>
      <h3>Support</h6>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse semper ipsum ut commodo tristique.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Support</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Edit

Using another icon it works ok.

[image]

Comment: It's not causing your problem, but you might want to fix the header tags. You currently have `<h3></h6>` for both of them.

Comment: What version of Font Awesome are you using?

Comment: @albertedevigo 4.1.0.

Comment: Fixed? You were using 4.1.0 and @Josh answer fixes it? I don't understand.

Comment: @albertedevigo I mean I fixed what he pointed out, not the actual problem.

Comment: What's the point in the down vote?

Comment: If you're using 4.1.0, then maybe try clearing the cache or something. It seems to be working using your code in my fiddle example. It doesn't work using version 4.0.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely with the version of Font Awesome you're using. You'll need to be using the latest version which is `4.1.0`. If you're using older versions then that icon hasn't been added yet. Here is a fiddle showing it working with the latest version.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mcfarljw/5Ecgq/

You can use the following CDN to test out the latest version:

`//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.css`

Answer (score 0):

I had this same trouble, and here was my solution. I had previously downloaded the FontAwesome package from GitHub and direct from their website, and this one "fa-life-ring" or "fa-support" icon was not displaying properly for me. Oddly enough, this one icon was displaying OK in Safari, but not in Chrome or Firefox or IE.

So I went to this CDN URL:
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.css

And grabbed the font files (EOT, SVG, TTF, and WOFF) referenced in this CSS file -- the font files actually hosted on their CDN -- and replaced the font files on my web server. (P.S. I only tested on a local development-only web server.)

Et voila, now it works. The only conclusion I can draw is that something is slightly different between GitHub and their CDN.